# How to allow the AR camera to move around the objects instead of with them

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, arcore, arcore-limitation

I'm using AR core and AR foundation and have managed to get some semblance of plane detection applied, (I am not using GPS or image tracking, just regular plane detection) but I need to mobilise my camera to be able to move around the objects. I tried messing with the inspector settings but I haven't achieved much. Any ideas or suggestions? In theory the scenes should look like they're placed onto the table. I also need to figure out how to navigate with one camera through multiple scenes.